# Need help on the proper use of a formula to produce a cambered airfoil

Tags: computational-geometry, trigonometry

Following the book on "*The Theory of Thin Wing Sections*" page #112 describes the method to combine a camber line (i.e Mean Line) and a thickness distribution to form a cambered wing section. Data derived from the function below will produce a symmetrical airfoil with no camber for the value is a percentage of chord.

```
yt[x_] := 
  Module[{t = .30,c = 1}, 
   (5*t*c*(.2969*Sqrt[x/c] + (-.1260)*(x/c) + (-.3516)*(x/c)^2 + .2843*(x/c)^3 + 
     (-.1015)*(x/c)^4))*1/2]

Plot[{yt[x], yt[x] - (yt[x]*2), yc[x]*.5}, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> .15]
```

[image: symmetrical Airfoil]

The function to derive the camber line (Mean Line) as a % of chord is listed below.

`m` = max thickness
`p` = position of max thickness in percentage of chord

```
(* forward of maximum ordinate *)
yc[x_] := 
  Module[{m = 0.02, p = .4}, (m (2 p x - x^2))/p^2]

(* aft of maximum ordinate *)
yc1[x_] := 
   Module[{m = 0.02, p = .4}, (m (1 - 2 p + 2 p x - x^2))/(1 - p)^2]

Show[Plot[yc[x], {x, 0, .4}], Plot[yc1[x], {x, .4, 1}],
  PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> .05]
```

[image: Plot of Mean Line]

Reproducing part of the PDF found on another site, a shorter version is found [here](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/airfoils/q0041.shtml), The root of my pain is I don't think I'm using the right trig function. If I were to use the formula $x-y\,t \sin(\theta)$, and I tried, but I didn't come close to the answer. How would I use $x-y\,t \sin(\theta)$ in *Mathematica*?

Below is a sample found in a PDF from "*The Theory of Thin Wing Sections*"

[image]

Comment: Maybe its me, but I can't figure out what is being asked here... what do you mean by how to use "x -yt sin(theta)" in Mathematica? Use it to do what? and where exactly do you want to use it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have to thank you for leading me down a fascinating rabbit hole! I have always found airfoil shapes enormously pleasing, but I was not aware of the NACA system.

For those who, like me, did not know much about the story, [NACA was the predecessor of NASA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Advisory_Committee_for_Aeronautics). They established some of the first airfoil definitions codified through mathematical relationships. For instance, a so called *four-digit NACA airfoil* such as "NACA 2415" is defined as follows:

- The length of an airfoil is called its *chord*. Here we use a parametric length of $1$, which can just be adjusted to any length necessary.
- The first digit in the NACA designation indicates the *maximum camber* $m$ (curvature) as a percentage of the cord (length): in this example 2%;
- The second digit indicates the position $p$ of the point of maximum curvature, in tenths of the chord measuring from the leading edge, i.e. the front; here it is at 4 tenths of the chords, i.e. 40% back;
- The last two digits indicate the maximum thickness $t$ of the airfoil as a percentage of the chord; here 15%.

These definitions come with standard formulae (linked in the OP's question) that allow you to calculate the shape of the airfoil. These functions are more conveniently defined using `Piecewise` below (here is [its documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)), rather than having the two separate definitions used by the OP.

```
m = 0.02; p = 0.40; t = 0.15; (* characteristics of NACA 2415*)

yc[x_] := Piecewise[{
   {m/p^2 (2 p x - x^2), 0 <= x < p},
   {m/(1 - p)^2 ((1 - 2 p) + 2 p x - x^2), p <= x <= 1}
   }]

yt[x_] := 5 t (0.2969 Sqrt[x] - 0.1260 x - 0.3516 x^2 + 0.2843 x^3 - 0.1015 x^4)
```

The final cambered profile is expressed using trigonometric functions of an angle $\theta=\arctan \frac{d{y_c}}{d{x}}$, shown below as the pre-calculated derivative. *Mathematica* will calculate this for you using `D[yc[x], x]`.

```
theta[x_] := ArcTan@ Piecewise[{
    {(m*(2*p - 2*x))/p^2, 0 <= x < p},
    {(m*(2*p - 2*x))/(1 - p)^2, p <= x <= 1}
    }]
```

Now we have all the machinery in place to **plot the shape of the cambered airfoil**.

In the NACA model the contour of the airfoil is expressed as a function of one parameter, i.e. the distance $x$ along the chord, so `ParametricPlot` ([docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)) is a natural fit here:

```
ParametricPlot[
 {
  {x - yt[x] Sin[theta[x]], yc[x] + yt[x] Cos[theta[x]]},
  {x + yt[x] Sin[theta[x]], yc[x] - yt[x] Cos[theta[x]]}
 },
 {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, Exclusions -> None
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice. Makes me remember when I wanted to be an aerospace engineer... Anyhoo, you can get rid of those breaks in your plot by using `Exclusions->None`. (+1)

Comment: @kale That's a good point: let me add that to the answer and fix the plot. Thank you for the upvote as well!

Comment: @MarcoB I have been tinkering with this for a long time. With little forward progress and learning MMA, I could not have found the solution without your help. I have a better understanding on a number of fronts.
Thank you: Bob Brooks

Comment: @MarcoB: I added {x,yc[x]} to see the mean line, your plot works nice.

Comment: @BobBrooks I'm delighted! As I said, thank you again for bringing up the problem, it was fun to delve into the airfoil shapes & equations. I was thinking about adding the chord and the mean lines to the plot as well: you don't need my help with that since you have it figured out already, but if I have the time I might add it to the answer anyway, just for the sake of completeness.