# How to merge two or more curves smoothly?

Tags: plotting, numerics, fitting

I have plotted three curves. For each range of $x$, one of those curves is true. On the other hand, finally, the result must be a unified curve. Is there any command to unify these three curves?

Actually the results are so complicated to bring here (Sorry)!
However, I have brought a toy-model in following:

```
Plot[{1 - 1/R, R^3 - 1}, {R, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"One", "Two"}]
```

It is worth mentioning that, I want the final curve to be as follows:

- After (before) the first (second) intersection point, it should be curve `two` 
  and elsewhere, curve `One`. Note that it is an approximation and the final plot 
  should be kind of smooth.
- This is the figure of my original problem. The blue dashed curve (only the right part)+the solid black one should be like the blue curves of the right panel.

[image: This is the figure of my original problem. The blue dashed curve (only the right part)+the solid black one should be like the blue curves of the right panel.]

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Piecewise`.

Comment: Or `Show`......

Comment: When the results are complicated, please take some time to write a simple toy model that represents more or less the situation you need to solve.

Comment: Are the parameters for these curves completely know or estimated?  If the parameters need to be estimated, are there restrictions on the join points such that the derivatives are continuous?  I ask the latter question because you mention the phrase "merge smoothly".

Comment: @JimB : In fact in the original problem, it is important to see the asymptotic behaviors for large and small values of $x$ axis variable. A small simplification in he curve doesn't matter.

Comment: I really would like to help I have no idea what your previous comment means.  And in the question "kind of smooth" seems to be in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Dear @JimB I have just attached a figure. I hope it could help.

Comment: This feels related: [(121615)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121615/121)

Answer (score 4):

```
colors = ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}; 

Plot[Min[{1 - 1/R, R^3 - 1}], {R, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#^3 - 1 - (1 - 1/#) &},  
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshShading -> Reverse[colors],
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[colors, {"One", "Two"}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, let

```
pw = PiecewiseExpand @ Min[{1 - 1/R, R^3 - 1}]
```

[image]

and use `pw` as the first argument in `Plot` above to get the same picture.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: The suggestion by Michael E2 has been taken into account.

If you don't want different colours for the different regions the following does the trick for you

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{x^3, -10 < x < 0}, {Log[x], 0 < x < 5}, {Sqrt[x], 5 < x < 10}}], 
  {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-2, 1}}, Exclusions -> None]
```

If you want different colours for the different bits, you can find an excellent analysis [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/plotting-piecewise-function-with-distinct-colors-in-each-section)

Comment: Might want to add `Exclusions -> None` if the curves are to be "unified." (Works better if the example functions join smoothly as the OP thinks theirs will.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 plus one. I totally missed that. Do you want to post a precise answer so I can delete mine or should I just add you suggestion?

Comment: Feel free to fix yours.  I have other work to get to... :)