# Plotting Joukowski Airfoil Streamlines using conformal maps

Tags: plotting, complex, finite-element-method, fluid-dynamics

I want to plot the streamlines around Joukowski Airfoil using conformal mapping of a circle solution.

I do know that there are a lot of solutions to plot the airfoil itself (for example [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119516/plotting-an-equation-describing-a-joukowski-airfoil)), but I'm having difficulties plotting the streamlines around the airfoil.

Generaly, the streamlines around a circle in 2D are described by the contours of the imaginary part of:

$$F\left(z\right)=U\left(z+\frac{a^2}{z}\right)$$

Where $a$ is the radius of the circle and $U$ is the velocity at infinite distance from it. To create the Joukowski airfiol you take a circle with center $\left(a,b\right)$ with radius $R>a$ and transform it under the following conformal map:

$$w\left(z\right)=z+\frac{1}{z}$$

And then you get something like shown in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119516/plotting-an-equation-describing-a-joukowski-airfoil).

**My problem is to plot the streamlines (the contours of $\textrm{Im}\left[F\left(z\right)\right]$) under the conformal transformation $w$.** I just can't understand how do you get the streamlines to transform.

I would appreciate any help, Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

To be more clear, what I want to get is something like that:
[image: Streamlines around Joukowski Airfoil. The airfoil was created by transforming with the circle described in the title.]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no simple method to display streamlines using the Zhukovsky function. I will show an example with a Zhukovsky profile at an angle of attack.

```
Clear[z]; U = rho = 1; chord = 4; thk = 0.5; alpha = 
 Pi/9; y0 = 0.2; x0 = -thk/5.2; L = chord/4; a = 
 Sqrt[y0^2 + L^2]; gamma = 4 Pi a U Sin[alpha + ArcCos[L/a]];
w[z_, sign_] := 
  Module[{zeta = (z + sign Sqrt[z^2 - 4 L^2])/2}, 
   zeta = (zeta - x0 - I y0) Exp[-I alpha]/Sqrt[(1 - x0)^2 + y0^2]; 
   U (zeta + a^2/zeta) + I gamma Log[zeta]/(2 Pi)];
sign[z_] := 
 Sign[Re[z]] If[
   Abs[Re[z]] < chord/2 && 
    0 < Im[z] < 2 y0 (1 - (2 Re[z]/chord)^2), -1, 1]; 
w[z_] := w[z, sign[z]]; V[z_] = D[w[z, sig], z] /. sig -> sign[z];
bg1 = ContourPlot[Im[w[(x + I y)]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Contours -> Table[x^3 + 0.0208, {x, -2, 2, 0.05}], 
  ContourStyle -> White, PlotPoints -> 40, Frame -> False, 
  Exclusions -> {Log[x + I y] == 0}]

J = Show[bg1, 
  StreamPlot[{Re[V[x + I y]], -Im[V[x + I y]]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 
    3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, StreamStyle -> LightGray, 
   Frame -> False, StreamPoints -> Fine]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can add animation for particles carried away by the flow

```
    Clear[z]; U = rho = 1; chord = 4; thk = 0.5; alpha = 
 Pi/9; y0 = 0.2; x0 = -thk/5.2; L = chord/4; a = 
 Sqrt[y0^2 + L^2]; gamma = 4 Pi a U Sin[alpha + ArcCos[L/a]];
w[z_, sign_] := 
  Module[{zeta = (z + sign Sqrt[z^2 - 4 L^2])/2}, 
   zeta = (zeta - x0 - I y0) Exp[-I alpha]/Sqrt[(1 - x0)^2 + y0^2]; 
   U (zeta + a^2/zeta) + I gamma Log[zeta]/(2 Pi)];
sign[z_] := 
 Sign[Re[z]] If[
   Abs[Re[z]] < chord/2 && 
    0 < Im[z] < 2 y0 (1 - (2 Re[z]/chord)^2), -1, 1]; 
w1[z_] := w[z, sign[z]]; VX = 
 Evaluate[D[w[z, s], z] /. {z -> x + I y, s -> sign[x + I y]}];



bg = ContourPlot[Im[w1[(x + I y)]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Contours -> Table[x^3 + 0.0208, {x, -1.75, 1.75, 0.05}], 
  ContourStyle -> White, Exclusions -> {Log[x + I y] == 0}, 
  ClippingStyle -> Red, Frame -> False]

pX = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == 
    Re[VX /. {x -> X[t], y -> Y[t]}], 
   Y'[t] == -Im[VX /. {x -> X[t], y -> Y[t]}], X[0] == -3, 
   Y[0] == yp}, X, {t, 0, 15}, {yp}]; pY = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == Re[VX /. {x -> X[t], y -> Y[t]}], 
   Y'[t] == -Im[VX /. {x -> X[t], y -> Y[t]}], X[0] == -3, 
   Y[0] == yp}, Y, {t, 0, 15}, {yp}];

pt = Table[
    Show[{bg, 
      Graphics[
       Table[{LightGray, PointSize[.01], 
         Point[Table[
           Evaluate[{pX[yp][t], pY[yp][t]}], {yp, -4, 1, .25}]]}, {t, 
         t0, t0 + 1, .1}]]}], {t0, 0, 12, .25}]; // Quiet

ListAnimate[pt]
```

[image: Figure 2]

It can be compared with the potential flow around aerodynamic profile NACA9415 (close in parameters to the Zhukovsky profile). Flow without circulation (with circulation see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167752/how-to-add-solutions-from-potential-flow-calculations-including-circulation/185808#185808))

```
ClearAll[NACA9415];
NACA9415[{m_, p_, t_}, x_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   yc = Piecewise[{{m/p^2 (2 p x - x^2), 
       0 <= x < p}, {m/(1 - p)^2 ((1 - 2 p) + 2 p x - x^2), 
       p <= x <= 1}}];
   yt = 5 t (0.2969 Sqrt[x] - 0.1260 x - 0.3516 x^2 + 0.2843 x^3 - 
       0.1015 x^4);
   \[Theta] = 
    ArcTan@Piecewise[{{(m*(2*p - 2*x))/p^2, 
        0 <= x < p}, {(m*(2*p - 2*x))/(1 - p)^2, p <= x <= 1}}];
   {{x - yt Sin[\[Theta]], 
     yc + yt Cos[\[Theta]]}, {x + yt Sin[\[Theta]], 
     yc - yt Cos[\[Theta]]}}];

m = 0.09;
p = 0.4;
tk = 0.15;
pe = NACA9415[{m, p, tk}, x];
ParametricPlot[pe, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, Exclusions -> None]
ClearAll[myLoop];
myLoop[n1_, n2_] := 
 Join[Table[{n, n + 1}, {n, n1, n2 - 1, 1}], {{n2, n1}}]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
rt = RotationTransform[-\[Pi]/9];(*angle of attack*)
a = Table[
  pe, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];(*table of coordinates around aerofoil*)
p0 = {p, tk/2};(*point inside aerofoil*)
x1 = -2; x2 = 3;(*domain dimensions*)
y1 = -2; y2 = 2;(*domain dimensions*)
coords = Join[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x1, y2}}, 
  rt@a[[All, 2]], rt@Reverse[a[[All, 1]]]];
nn = Length@coords;
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[myLoop[1, 4]], 
     LineElement[myLoop[5, nn]]}, "RegionHoles" -> {rt@p0}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];

ClearAll[x, y, \[Phi]];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[\[Phi][x, y], x, x] + D[\[Phi][x, y], y, y] == 
     NeumannValue[1, x == x1 && y1 <= y <= y2] + 
      NeumannValue[-1, x == x2 && y1 <= y <= y2], 
    DirichletCondition[\[Phi][x, y] == 0, 
     x == 0 && y == 0]}, \[Phi], {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
ClearAll[vel];
vel[x_, y_] := Evaluate[Grad[sol[x, y], {x, y}]]



st = StreamPlot[vel[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, .5}, 
  Epilog -> {Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  StreamPoints -> Fine, StreamStyle -> LightGray];
dp = ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -.5, 1.5}, {y, -.5, .5}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Epilog -> {Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, Contours -> 20]

bac = Show[dp, st]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Add animation

```
pX = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == vel[X[t], Y[t]][[1]], 
   Y'[t] == vel[X[t], Y[t]][[2]], X[0] == -1/2, Y[0] == y0}, 
  X, {t, 0, 5}, {y0}]; pY = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == vel[X[t], Y[t]][[1]], 
   Y'[t] == vel[X[t], Y[t]][[2]], X[0] == -1/2, Y[0] == y0}, 
  Y, {t, 0, 5}, {y0}];

pt = Table[
    Show[{dp, 
      Graphics[
       Table[{LightGray, PointSize[.01], 
         Point[Table[
           Evaluate[{pX[y0][t], 
             pY[y0][t]}], {y0, -.5, .6, .0505}]]}, {t, t0, 
         t0 + .5, .05}]]}], {t0, 0, 2.2, .1}]; // Quiet

ListAnimate[pt]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Finally, using the nonlinear FEM implemented in version 12, it is possible to calculate the viscous flow for profile NACA9415. Here we see a different picture, not similar to the potential flow.

```
ClearAll[NACA9415];
NACA9415[{m_, p_, t_}, x_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   yc = Piecewise[{{m/p^2 (2 p x - x^2), 
       0 <= x < p}, {m/(1 - p)^2 ((1 - 2 p) + 2 p x - x^2), 
       p <= x <= 1}}];
   yt = 5 t (0.2969 Sqrt[x] - 0.1260 x - 0.3516 x^2 + 0.2843 x^3 - 
       0.1015 x^4);
   \[Theta] = 
    ArcTan@Piecewise[{{(m*(2*p - 2*x))/p^2, 
        0 <= x < p}, {(m*(2*p - 2*x))/(1 - p)^2, p <= x <= 1}}];
   {{x - yt Sin[\[Theta]], 
     yc + yt Cos[\[Theta]]}, {x + yt Sin[\[Theta]], 
     yc - yt Cos[\[Theta]]}}];

m = 0.09;
pk = 0.4;
tk = 0.15;
pe = NACA9415[{m, pk, tk}, x];
ParametricPlot[pe, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, Exclusions -> None]
ClearAll[myLoop];
myLoop[n1_, n2_] := 
 Join[Table[{n, n + 1}, {n, n1, n2 - 1, 1}], {{n2, n1}}]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
rt = RotationTransform[-\[Pi]/16];(*angle of attack*)
a = Table[pe, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];(*table of coordinates around aerofoil*)


p0 = {pk, tk/2};(*point inside aerofoil*)
x1 = -2; x2 = 3;(*domain dimensions*)
y1 = -2; y2 = 2;(*domain dimensions*)
coords = Join[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x1, y2}}, 
   rt@a[[All, 2]], rt@Reverse[a[[All, 1]]]];
nn = Length@coords;
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[myLoop[1, 4]], 
     LineElement[myLoop[5, nn]]}, "RegionHoles" -> {rt@p0}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0005]; yU = 
 Interpolation[rt@a[[All, 1]], InterpolationOrder -> 2];
yL = Interpolation[rt@a[[All, 2]], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 2]; mesh["Wireframe"]
op = {Inactive[
       Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
         u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
       y}] + \[Rho] {{u[x, y], v[x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][
        u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y], 
    Inactive[
       Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
         v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
       y}] + \[Rho] {{u[x, y], v[x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][
        v[x, y], {x, y}] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]} /. {\[Mu] -> 1/1000, \[Rho] -> 1};
pde = op == {0, 0, 0};
bcs = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == x1 || y == y1 || y == y2],
   DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x == x1 || y == y1 || y == y2], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, 
    0 <= x <= Cos[Pi/16]], 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0., x == x2]};
{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs}, {u, v, p}, Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];
sp = StreamPlot[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}, {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, StreamPoints -> Fine, 
  StreamStyle -> LightGray, Epilog -> {Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]}]

dp1 = DensityPlot[
  Norm[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 60, 
  Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  Epilog -> {Gray, Line[coords[[5 ;; nn]]]}]

Show[dp1, sp]
```

[image: Figire 6]

Comment: I have *no idea* if this is correct, but +1 for pretty. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. There is nothing to compare, but the code for `w` was published somewhere. I added `V` and removed the rotation angle.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am trying to reproduce (on V12) the animation but `bg` is not defined. Using `bg1` results in the error "Coordinate {ParametricFunction[1, Internal`Bag[{Hold[ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][$CellContext`X][$CellContext`t] == Re[$CellContext`V], Derivative[1][$CellContext`Y][$CellContext`t] == -Im[$CellContext`V], $CellContext`X[0] == -3, $CellContext`Y[0] == $Ce should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I'm sorry. I added code for the animation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Beautiful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of related examples out there that may be of use to you such as [Potential Flow over a NACA Four-Digit Airfoil](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PotentialFlowOverANACAFourDigitAirfoil/) and some of the other demonstrations by [Richard Fearn](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/author.html?author=Richard%20L.%20Fearn), along with William Shaw's [*Complex Analysis with Mathematica*](https://www.cambridge.org/jp/academic/subjects/mathematics/real-and-complex-analysis/complex-analysis-mathematica?format=HB&isbn=9780521836265) book, especially the Chapter 16 (Conformal mapping I: simple mappings and Mobius transforms) and Chapter 19 (Elementary applications to two-dimensional physics).